# Conditionally add character to a string

Tags: r, string

I am trying to add 0s into character strings, but only under certain conditions.

I have a vector of file names like such:

```
my.fl <- c("res_P1_R1.rds", "res_P2_R1.rds",
  "res_P1_R19.rds", "res_P2_R2.rds",
  "res_P10_R1.rds", "res_P10_R19.rds")
```

I want to `sort(my.fl)` so that the file names are ordered by the numbers following the `P` and `R`, but as it stands sorting results in this:

```
 "res_P1_R1.rds"   "res_P1_R19.rds"  "res_P10_R1.rds"  "res_P10_R19.rds" "res_P2_R1.rds"   "res_P2_R2.rds"
```

To fix this I need to add 0s after `P` and `R`, but only when the following number ranges from `1-9`, if the following number is `> 9` I want to do nothing.

The result should be as follows:

```
"res_P01_R01.rds"   "res_P01_R19.rds"  "res_P10_R01.rds"  "res_P10_R19.rds" "res_P02_R01.rds"   "res_P02_R02.rds"
```

and if I sort it, it is ordered as expected e.g.:

```
"res_P01_R01.rds" "res_P01_R19.rds" "res_P02_R01.rds" "res_P02_R02.rds" "res_P10_R01.rds" "res_P10_R19.rds"
```

I can add 0s based on position, but since the required position changes my solution only works on a subset of the file names. I think this would be a common problem but I haven't managed to find an answer on SO (or anywhere), any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `mixedsort` from the `gtools` package which removes the need to insert zeroes.

```
my.fl <- c("res_P1_R1.rds", "res_P2_R1.rds",
           "res_P1_R19.rds", "res_P2_R2.rds",
           "res_P10_R1.rds", "res_P10_R19.rds")

library(gtools)

mixedsort(my.fl)

[1] "res_P1_R1.rds"   "res_P1_R19.rds"  "res_P2_R1.rds"   "res_P2_R2.rds"   "res_P10_R1.rds"  "res_P10_R19.rds"
```

But if you do want to insert the zeroes you could use something like:

```
sort(gsub("(?<=\\D)(\\d{1})(?=\\D)", "0\\1", my.fl, perl = TRUE))

[1] "res_P01_R01.rds" "res_P01_R19.rds" "res_P02_R01.rds" "res_P02_R02.rds" "res_P10_R01.rds" "res_P10_R19.rds"
```